# reassign an existing remote repo to my local repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I don't get something here about Git/Bitbucket, but I'm not sure what exactly.  A bit out of my depth, perhaps.

I have a project which has laid dormant for a year, and which has somehow lost its connection to Bitbucket.  How do I reassign an existing remote origin to my local repo?

I did a local git commit (which worked fine), but when I did `git pull` in advance of a push, I got this:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

I tried:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repo>.git master
```

...which didn't work.  I got this:

```
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repo>.git' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

I know I have a BitBucket repo for this project (visiting BitBucket in my browser confirms this), and the project status is only one commit behind.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repo>.git master
```

Try using

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

And afterwards, run a `git fetch`.